# "Not Equal" != into Python 3 not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to switch a code from Python 2.7.10 to Python 3, and some things aren't working. I just recently was introduced to Python.

```
choice = 2
while choice != 1 and choice != 0:
    choice = input("Hello, no.")
    if choice != 1 and choice != 0:
       print("Not a good code.")
```

How do I change the "!=" into something Python 3 will understand? When I type in 1 or 0, it gives me my "hello, no" invalid print.

Comment: First, learn to indent your code. Second, `input` in Python3 returns a string. You must convert it to an `int` before comparing. Third,you may find this document useful: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html

Comment: @DYZ: That looks like the opposite of this question...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers

Comment: choices = 2
        choice=str(choices)
        while choice != '1' and choice != '0':
            choice = input("Hello, no.")
            if choice != '1' and choice != '0':
                print("Not a good code.")

Answer (score 1):

The `input` function returns user input as a string. You can convert it to a number using the `int` and `float` methods:

```
choice = 2
while choice != 1 and choice != 0:
    choice = input("Hello, no.")
    choice = int(choice)
    if choice != 1 and choice != 0:
       print("Not a good code.")
```

Answer (score 1):

`input` in Python 3 is equivalent to Python 2's `raw_input`; it reads a string, it doesn't try to `eval` it. This is because `eval` of user input is intrinsically unsafe.

If you want to do this safely in Python 3, you can wrap the call to `input` in `int` to convert to `int`, or in `ast.literal_eval` to interpret arbitrary Python literals without opening yourself up to arbitrary code execution.

```
import ast

choice = 2
while choice != 1 and choice != 0:
    choice = ast.literal_eval(input("Hello, no."))
    if choice != 1 and choice != 0:
       print("Not a good code.")
```